# session messages not appearing in laravel 10?

Tags: php, laravel

I tried all the solutions available but in my laravel sessions, messages do not appear.
if i use session put and add a key and value that goes in blade successfully.
css and js are also  working fine

**Controller code**

```
$userService->updateUser($authService->userObject, $request->only('email', 'first_name', 'last_name'));
    $producerService->updateProducer($producerObject, $request->except('email', '_token'));

    if ($request->hasFile('avatar') && $request->file('avatar')->isValid()) {
        $avatarService->saveAvatar($producerObject->avatar(), $request->file('avatar'));
    }
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Item created successfully!');
```

**Blade alert code**

```
 @if ($message = Session::get('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 
        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
</div>
@endif
```

**Route has web middleware as well**

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'producer',
    'middleware' => ['web','auth.account:producer'],
    'as' => 'app.',
    'namespace' => 'Producer',
], function () {}


protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
```

Comment: have you verified the session value? debug the session value and check what is it's value

Comment: also please remove $message from if statement and output like this  {{ session()->get('success') }}

Comment: yes session success returns null and session all returns   empty old and new"_flash" => array:2 [▼
    "old" => []
    "new" => []
  ]

Answer (score 0):

I think it should works.

```
@if (Session::has('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button> 
            <strong>{{ session('success') }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```